# D3 updating colors in co-occurence chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

https://hansardbrowser.s3.amazonaws.com/Cooccurmatrix/index%20%2812.12.2015%207.43.36%20PM%29.html

I am currently trying to recreate the co-occurrence matrix from the D3 Les Miserables demo.

I am able to add more variables to the "order" drop down list, and I am currently trying to add the code to change the color as well.

The current setting defaults to "party" as the color option, but how can I insert the new coloroption value into the .style code and refresh?

Original grouping change code:

```
d3.select("#order").on("change", function() {
clearTimeout(timeout);
order(this.value);
});

  function order(value) {
    x.domain(orders[value]);

var t = svg.transition().duration(2500);

t.selectAll(".row")
    .delay(function(d, i) { return x(i) * 4; })
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + x(i) + ")"; })
  .selectAll(".cell")
    .delay(function(d) { return x(d.x) * 4; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); });

t.selectAll(".column")
    .delay(function(d, i) { return x(i) * 4; })
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + x(i) + ")rotate(-90)"; });
  }
```

My attempt to add the color change function in (sorry i am extremely new to D3 and javascript)

```
d3.select("#coloroption").on("change", function() {
coloroption(this.value);
});
function coloroption(value) {
 var cell = d3.select(this).selectAll(".cell")
    .data(row.filter(function(d) { return d.z; }))
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "cell")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", x.rangeBand())
    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return z(d.z); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return nodes[d.x].(coloroption[value]) == nodes[d.y].(coloroption[value])  ? c(nodes[d.x].(coloroption[value]) ) : null; })
    //.on("mouseover", mouseover)
   // .on("mouseout", mouseout);
   }
```

Not sure if this is the right way I should handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `.(coloroption[value])` is not valid javascript; you need to access the properties using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).  The `d3` portion of this is then a simple `.selectAll` with a style change:

```
d3.select("#coloroption").on("change", function() {
  // get selected value from dropdown
  var opt = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  svg.selectAll(".cell")
    .style("fill", function(d){
      // get it by bracket notation
      return nodes[d.x][opt] == nodes[d.y][opt]  ? c(nodes[d.x][opt]) : null;
    })
});
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/U1CSWmlb6EBorxo0z15j?p=preview).

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! =) I guess I better take some Javascript lessons from W3schools to get the fundamentals right. Thank you for your quick help!